# Android Google Maps API Разобрать Address

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, address

В Google Maps API есть класс Address, конкретный адрес.

**В чем у меня проблема:**

Есть адрес (как пример) - *"Россия Москва Молдагуловой ул., 10"*
Поиск возвращает адрес который можно разобрать примерно следующим образом:

- **Улицу** можно получить так: **address.getThoroughfare();** (*Молдагуловой ул.*)
- **Дом**, корпус и строение : **address.getSubThoroughfare();** (*10*)
- Полный адрес: **address.getAddressLine(0);** (*Молдагуловой ул., 10*)

**address.getAddressLine(1);** - Город
**address.getAddressLine(2);** - Страна
**address.getAddressLine(3);** - Почтовый индекс

Это подходит для большинства адресов.

Кроме некоторых.

Вот к примеру еще один адрес: *"Россия Москва Юности ул., 1"*

На что вернется следующая картина:

- **address.getThoroughfare();** = NULL
- **address.getSubThoroughfare();** = NULL

**address.getAddressLine(0);** - Дом 
**address.getAddressLine(1);** - Улица
**address.getAddressLine(2);** - Города
**address.getAddressLine(3);** - Страна
 
**address.getAddressLine(4);** - Почтовый индекс

Понятно что я могу проверить не возвращается ли на address.getThoroughfare(); - NULL и обработать по другому алгоритму адресс.

Ну а что если есть адреса, где под теми же индексами возвращается другие данные. Где гарантии?!

**Как достоверно разобрать возвращаемый адрес на составляющие?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно значения достаете. Надо следующим образом:

```
region = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
homeNumber = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
street = addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
```

Comment: Опять же - addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare(); вернет NULL во втором случае.

Comment: Был не прав! Просто адрес не правильно формировал! Не добавлялось - "Россия Москва" и видать где то есть еще улица Юности, 1. А молдагуловой больше нет. Спасибо!

Comment: =) всегда пожалуйста